# Unable to install boto in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto

I am trying to install boto from the source code / pypi, but I am unable to install it using python 3.2. Why is it failing?

```
c:\boto>..\Python32\python.exe setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 35, in <module>
    from boto import __version__
  File "c:\boto\boto\__init__.py", line 26, in <mod
ule>
    from boto.pyami.config import Config, BotoConfigLocations
  File "c:\boto\boto\pyami\config.py", line 185
    print s.getvalue()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
print s.getvalue()
```

is Python 2 syntax. From the `README`:

> If you are interested in trying out boto with Python 3.x, check out the [`neo`](https://github.com/boto/boto/tree/neo) branch. This is under active development and the goal is a version of boto that works in Python 2.6, 2.7, and 3.x. Not everything is working just yet but many things are and it's worth a look if you are an active Python 3.x user.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working on Python 3 by installing from the develop branch as the PyPI version did not work at the time of writing. E.g. add this to your `requirements.txt`:

```
git+https://github.com/boto/boto.git@develop
```

Once you find a working version, it's good to freeze your dependency to a specific commit, e.g.:

```
git+https://github.com/boto/boto.git@5a28d1c6a3b11b979bf32ea7fbfd6d5156c01395
```

(ideally, of course, we wouldn't need to install from a repository in the first place :)

**Update 2015 –** can be installed directly from PyPI. See David's comment below.

Comment: has this changed since 2014?

Comment: Could be. Maybe give it a try with a plain Cheese Shop package and we can update the info here :)

Comment: Ok, boto seems to work out of the "cheese shop" (Had to google that, it's PyPI for the uninitiated). The thing that was not working was django-storages. You need djanog-storages-redux additionally